# Некорректная работа функции free()

Tags: c

Столкнулся с очень интересным случаем: при вызове функции free() для освобожнения блока динамического массива размерностью [3х1] происходит аварийное завершение программы.
При других размерах массива работает без проблем. Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему так происходит.

Вот листинг:

```
//Read array
printf("Specify dimentions for array:\n");
printf("M="); scanf("%d", &M);
printf("N="); scanf("%d", &N);
A=(int *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(int));  //выделение памяти под массив данных из целого типа
readArray(A, M, N);                //заполнение массива
//print array
printArray(A, M, N);               //чтение и вывод массива
free(A);                           //освобождение массива
```

---

Мои функции:

```
void readArray(int *A, int M, int N) //1, 2
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
        for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
            printf("A[%d][%d]=", i+1, j+1); 
            scanf("%d",(A+i*M+j));
        }
}

void printArray(int *A, int M, int N)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\nOur array is [%dx%d]:\n", M, N);
    for(i=0; i<M; i++) {   
        for(j=0; j<N; j++) printf("%3d", *(A+i*M+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Компилятор, система?

Comment: Что если закомментировать вызовы ``readArray(A, M, N)`` и ``printArray(A, M, N)``? Тоже падает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда, когда при освобождении памяти возникает ошибка, надо искать проблему в записи за пределы этого блока. У тебя это функция readArray, конкретнее - вызов scanf. Кроме неё у тебя больше никто не записывает в массив. Значит ошибку искать надо только в вызове scanf. Ошибка в вычислении индекса в коде `A+i*M+j`. Надо исправить либо на `A+i*N+j`, либо на `A+j*M+i`.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял ошибку!
На будущее буду по-внимательней, вопрос действительно тупиковый

Answer (score 1):

А почему при индексации i надо умножать на M, а не на N? Уже при i=2,j=1 индекс выходит за границы.

```
scanf("%d",(A+i*M+j));
```